# How to assign minimum value based on rank in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'],
  ...:                     'rank': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  ...:                     'value': [8, 6, np.nan, 7, 9, np.nan, 4, np.nan]})
Out[4]: 
   A  rank  value
0  A     1    8.0
1  B     2    6.0
2  C     3    NaN
3  D     4    7.0
4  E     5    9.0
5  F     6    NaN
6  G     7    4.0
7  H     8    NaN
```

For all NaN values I would like to assign the minimum value of the group of items that are ranked above its own rank.

Logic:

C has a rank of 3, the 2 items ranked above (A and B) the minimum value is 6, so C should be assigned a value of 6

F has a rank of 6, the items ranked above (A, B, C, D, E) the minimum value is 6, so C should be assigned a value of 6

H has a rank of 8, the items ranked above (A, B, C, D, E, F, G) the minimum value is 4, so H should be assinged a value of 4

resulting dataframe should look like this

```
   A  rank  value
0  A     1    8.0
1  B     2    6.0
2  C     3    6.0
3  D     4    7.0
4  E     5    9.0
5  F     6    6.0
6  G     7    4.0
7  H     8    4.0
```

How can this be achieved with 1 or 2 lines of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate the cumulative minimum for all rows. Fill the `Na` with `fillna`

```
df['mincum'] = df['value'].expanding().min()
df['value'] = df['value'].fillna(df['mincum'])
df
```

Usinfg `Series.cummin`

```
df['mincum'] = df['value'].cummin(skipna=True).ffill()
df['value'] = df['value'].fillna(df['mincum'])
```

One-lines without using additional helper columns.

`expanding.mean`:

```
df['value'] = df['value'].fillna(df['value'].expanding().min())
```

`Series.cummin`

```
df['value'] = df['value'].fillna(df['value'].cummin(skipna=True).ffill())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
adf = df[df['value'].isnull()]
for i, r in adf.iterrows():
  df.loc[i, 'value'] = df[df['rank'] < r['rank']]['value'].values.min()
```

If you have duplicate ranks with some being NaNs then:

```
adf = df[df['value'].isnull()]
bdf = df[~df['value'].isnull()]
for i, r in adf.iterrows():
  df.loc[i, 'value'] = bdf[bdf['rank'] < r['rank']]['value'].values.min()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another try:

```
idx = df.loc[df['value'].isnull(),'value'].index
for i in idx:
    df.loc[i,'value'] = df.loc[:i-1,'value'].min()
```

Prints:

```
   A  rank  value
0  A     1    8.0
1  B     2    6.0
2  C     3    6.0
3  D     4    7.0
4  E     5    9.0
5  F     6    6.0
6  G     7    4.0
7  H     8    4.0
```